# How does Rey removing the Falcon's compressor hurt Poe later?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-rise-of-skywalker

I read an [article from ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-rey-poe-problem-millennium-falcon-compressor/) that was about this subtle connection between ep7 and ep9. The author says that because Rey removed the compressor in ep7 the Millennium Falcon is then badly damaged when Poe does the lightspeed skipping through several systems.

Maybe I am missing something and I will admit I'm not a Star Wars nut, but how does her removing the compressor result in the ship taking extra damage?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the transcript, my reading wasn't that this was caused by Rey bypassing Unkar Platt's after-market ignition line compressor, which she did in *Force Awakens*, but rather that a similarly named component (and possibly one that does much the same job) was known to be broken when they took off to go and meet the spy.

Rey is angry that Poe, **knowing that the Falcon's compressor was in need of repair**, still decided to stress the hyperdrive with a series of short jumps.

> **Rey:** *You lightspeed skipped!?*
>
> **Poe:** [defensive] *Yeah, well it got us back here*
>
> **Rey:** *The compressor's down*
>
> **Poe:** *I know, I was there*

Note that she knows exactly what's caused the fires with only a casual visual inspection.

> **Rey:** *You blew both sub-alternators*

Comment: But doesnt the article sound like it is a direct correlation between Rey bypassing the compressor and the ship taking major damage when light speed skipping?

Comment: It's possible that Han left it there and Rey never removed it. I don't think that's very likely, 3+ years later...

Comment: I think Chewie had a thing or two to say in the middle of that conversation, before she indicated she knew the sub-alternators were blown.  I'm thinking she got that detail from him.  Like Poe got the detail "you dropped a tree on him" from BB8.